# Addthis facebook share/like custom popup window in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-like, addthis

Hello developers out there. :)

I have a website which need a facebook share/like button but with a custom image instead of the standard blue facebook icon. In addition to Facebook Platform Policies: http://developers.facebook.com/policy/ *You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as the Like button or Like box plugin.*
 
So the standard like button from facebook is not an option. However if I use Addthis I can specify a custom image for my facebook button like this and a custom URL which read from the property addThisURL.

```
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook" addthis:url='<%= addThisURL %>'>
        <asp:Image ID="Image5" ImageUrl="/images/icon-facebook.png" AlternateText="Share on facebook" ToolTip="Share on facebook" runat="server" /></a>
```

And it works perfectly. :) But when a user click the facebook button a new tab opens in the browser. I want, when the user click the button the share/like page will show in a small popup window or a small overlay window.
I have search around, but not able to find a solution. And seems I am not the only one with that problem: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/168350-facebook-button-popup-problem 
I have tried with standard javascript popup window script, but since I do not have anything to href the script will not work. Any help or advice will be much appreciated. :)